# How to open same modal on click of common class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a model on click of same link, but when i click only backdrop apprears in one blink then it reloads the page. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="openmodal"><a href="">click</a></li>
<li class="openmodal"><a href="">click</a></li>
<li class="openmodal"><a href="">click</a></li>
</ul>



 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalnew" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.openmodal').click({
  $('#modalnew').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `.`add `.` for class.

Try this

```
$('.openmodal').click({
  $('#modalnew').modal('show');
});
```

**Edit**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li class="openmodal"><a href="#">click</a></li>
<li class="openmodal"><a href="#">click</a></li>
<li class="openmodal"><a href="#">click</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('.openmodal').on('click', function (e) {
  $('#modalnew').modal('show');
});
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/927/)**

Comment: It seems, working in jsfiddle but it's not working in my project. Does it matter to have 5 more same lists items ?

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas Pai, It's working now That was my bad. I have not added # in anchor tags.

Answer (score -1):

Check your syntax, you missed "function()"

```
$('.openmodal').click(function(){
  $('#modalnew').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Any reason for down-voting?